# unix sed search replace Section sign §

Tags: search, replace, sed

I want to replace a Section sign "§" in CSV files.
So i try some sed commands, but it did not work for me.

i tried:

sed -i 's/§/\;/g' file.csv

sed -i 's/\§/\;/g' file.csv

Is it a SED or Shell issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of `sed` and what `OS` are you using? It works for me. `sed` v4.2.1 on `OEL` v6.4.

Comment: The CSV file is ANSI coded. if i convert the file to UTF-8 the sed replace works.
So why sed will not find the § in ANSI coded file?